# Can't Re-enable Magento Cache in admin

Tags: caching, magento

I am having performance problems with my website and after profiling noticed that it looked like the cache was not being loaded.  So I went to admin and looked at the Cache Management page and all caches were disabled.  I re-enabled them and sometimes one will show as enabled, sometimes none will.

When I am able to get Configuration cache to show as enabled, I can view the profiler on the front end and see the line:

mage::app::init::config::load_cache

This line was not showing in the profiler before I enabled the cache.  However, after a short period of time (30 seconds or so), any caches that were enabled show as disabled again and the front end profiler no longer has this line (the cache isn't being used).

So far, I can not get the cache to stay on.  I have apache ownership on the var/cache and 777 permissions.  The files are created there initially, but I am also use apc cache.

Configuration is:

`<cache>
             <backend>apc</backend>
             <prefix>SH_</prefix> </cache>`

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using?

Comment: 1.5.0.1 is the version i'm using.  upgrading right now is not an option

Comment: The enabled/disabled settings are stored in the `core_cache_option` table. What is the values there? If you enable/disable caches?

Comment: As i enable various caches in the admin, i can see a record added with value 1.  However, after time elapses, the admin shows all as disabled, but the records are still in the table until I try to re-enable a cache, which replaces the records in the table with only the cache i choose to enable.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `<prefix>SH_</prefix>` setting to something that is guaranteed to be unique, e.g. your database name.

**Background**

Given the information you provided, I suspect another Magento instance is running on the same machine with the same cache prefix.
Whenever you change the settings, Magento writes them to the database, and then also saves the cache (see `Mage_Core_Model_Cache::_initOptions()`). Because the Magento instances share the same fast backend cache pool (because of the identical prefix), the settings are also used by the other host. Once the cache is cleared by the other host, their (disabled) setting is written to the cache. Now your Instance also sees the caches as disabled.

I'm unable to provide evidence without the option to test, but, well, this is my best guess.

Comment: i have adjusted the prefix before, but tried again- still see the same behavior.  This magento instance is the only instance on this server as well.  I can see in APC the cache files created and accessed, but when the admin switches to disabled, the # of hits on the cache also stops increasing... it's like magento is deciding not to use the cache for some reason on it's own

Comment: What happens if you disable the apc caching by commenting out the whole `<cache>` section of the local.xml? Does Magento work with the default files cache backend?

Comment: yes it does work.  also, the apc cache appears to work now and I can't replicate the issue with cache being disabled in admin randomly.  Using the profiler, i can see load cache and the mage entry shows about .6 seconds, which is probably ok.  Unfortunately, the site still is intermittantly slow- 8-10 seconds to load vs sometimes it's basically instant.  Guess caching was only part of the problem...

Comment: also, if i try to run php index.php, i get warning: 
PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Running PHP with APC from the command line is problematic, unless Apache also uses the same user id. One reason is that it has to access the same shared memory segments. Regarding the performance, the profiler should be able to give you more information about the bottleneck. Also, I recommend the Magento performance white paper for the environment setup (http://www.magentocommerce.com/whitepaper).

Comment: I ran profiler- there is no bottleneck in magento from what i can tell after cache is enabled and working.  mage() runs in .7 seconds even though the page takes 7 seconds to load in a browser.

Comment: Sounds like a non-Magento issue then. Try the YSLow or PageSpeed Firefox plugins.